# AngularJS - $watch not triggered even though value changed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using AngularJS with twitter bootstrap.

I have a table and this table belongs to the Parent Controller.
I have a popup and this belongs to the Child Controller.

When the user clicks on a row in the table, the popup is displayed and it contains more information about the row selected.

This is how my current code looks like:

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    //called when a row is clicked
    $scope.showMoreInfo = function() {
        $scope.showModal = true;
    }
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('showModal', function() {
        if($scope.$parent.showModal !== true) {
            return;
        }

        //Show the popup - #myModal is the ID of the popup div 
        jQuery("#myModal").modal("show");
    });

    //When the popup is closed, change the value
    jQuery("#myModal).on("hide", function() {
        $scope.$parent.showModal = false;
    });
}
```

Now, this mechanism works perfectly - when the user clicks on the row, the popup is shown containing the details of the row (I transfer the details from the ParentCtrl to ChildCtrl using a service that I did not include here to focus on the issue at hand).
When the user clicks on the "X" or the close button in the popup, the modal closes as expected. Further clicks on the row also work smoothly and the popup is shown as expected.

**My issue lies when** the popup is closed by clicking on the area outside the popup. Basically, if you have worked with the bootstrap modals (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), you will know that there is an area outside the popup that faintly displays the web page in the background and that the popup can be closed by clicking on an area outside the popup too - that is not via "X" or Close buttons in the popup but by simply clicking outside the popup container.

Although the `jQuery("#myModal").on('hide', function() {..});` is called which sets the value of `$scope.$parent.showModal` to false, the `$scope.$watch(..)` is never triggered.
When the user clicks on another row after closing the popup in this manner, although the `$scope.showModal` is set to true, the `$scope.$watch(..)` is again not triggered.

Any idea what goes wrong when the user closes the popup the abnormal way and what could be a solution here?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq ? Especially the Common Pitfall -> Dom Manipulation section ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out; although I need to work more on AngularJS to understand why I had to move the DOM manipulation to a directive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time an scope property changes outside Angular oversee (as in case of DOM events), you need to cause a `$digest` cycle.

To do so, add a $scope.$apply() just after changing the property.

```
//When the popup is closed, change the value
jQuery("#myModal).on("hide", function() {
    $scope.$parent.showModal = false;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Anyway, as @ganaraj said, read [Common Pitfall -> Dom Manipulation section](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq). You **must** enclose **all dom manipulations** in a directive, **never** inside a controller.

Comment: I shifted the code to inside a directive and even then the issue occurred. I had to use `$scope.$apply()` to make it work inside the directive too (I was thinking otherwise). Anyhow, apparently, the correct way is `$scope.$apply(function() {$scope.$parent.showModal = false}); - something to do with exceptions. Its explained [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho) around the 24 minute mark...